# Move cursor in Sublime Text Python Plugin

Tags: python, sublimetext

I wrote a simple plugin for Sublime Text which inserts tags at cursor position(s) or wraps them around selected text:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin
class mySimpleCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
  def run(self, edit):
    sels = self.view.sel()
    for sel in sels:
      sel.start = sel.a if (sel.a < sel.b) else sel.b
      sel.end = sel.b if (sel.a < sel.b) else sel.a
      insert1Length = self.view.insert(edit, sel.start, '<tag>')
      self.view.insert(edit, sel.end + insert1Length, '</tag>')
```

But how can I move the cursor(s) after inserting the tags? I looked at the API documentation in https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html and at several example plugins but still fail to solve this silly problem. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have your tried using `set_viewport_position()`?

Comment: Where do you want to move the cursor? I remember I struggled with this a little the first time I wrote plugins as well, and if I recall correctly the property you are looking for is the "Region" class. The notion of _cursors_ which we are accustomed to is flawed as we can have multiple "regions" marked simultaneously, and thus at least I got confused at first.

Comment: martineau: No, but this doesn't seem the right thing - according to the API it scrolls the viewport instead of moving the cursor(s). Plus, I'm not sure how to set a vector as function argument (as you can guess I don't usually work with Python).

Comment: pingul: I never saw someone moving the regions, they only delete them and create them anew. That makes it necessary to save them in advance. I ended up lifting lots of code from indentation.py. That works -- for the price that my simple plugin is four times as long and I don't really understand it anymore. There should be an easier way.

Comment: @wortwart Yes, isn't that the whole point (i.e. to delete them and create new)? What is the difference between deleting and creating new, and to "move" as you state it? P.S. Use the @-next time so we get notified that you responded :)

Comment: @pingul Sorry for the missing @.
In all examples I saw all regions are deleted at once with clear() which makes it necessary to store them in advance instead of simply doing that in the edit loop. What should be something like "sel.move_region(-4)" or "sel.a -= 4" took me 50 lines ... (I'm sure it could be done with less effort, though).

Comment: @wortwart But can't you implement the `move_region` yourself then? Something like 
`def move_region(region, distance):
    new_region = Region(region.a + distance, region.b + distance)
    RegionSet.add(new_region)
    RegionSet.remove(region)`

Comment: Formatting becomes somewhat weird in the comments, but I hope you can parse the snippet.

Comment: @pingul Looks perfectly sensible but doesn't work. It's `sublime.Region` instead of `Region` and it should be (according to the doc) `sublime.RegionSet` which doesn't work either, though. I suppose with my lack in Python skills, superficial documentation and a somewhat difficult API I should leave it with my not-so-perfect but working solution. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I published my solution here:
https://gist.github.com/wortwart/9778c13408711b4e419c

Comment: If you want to move the cursor by characters or lines there is already a command that does that and is invoked when you press the right arrow (move 1 character right) or the left arrow. Maybe is easier for you to use view.run_command ?

Comment: @sergioFC: Ah, yes, good idea. It works now with:
`for x in range(0, insertCloseLength):
 view.run_command("move", {"by": "characters", "forward": False})`
Thanks!

Comment: Cool you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same problem - moving the cursor to the end of a line in a plugin after appending text to it.
I fixed it using sergioFC's hint of:

```
# Place cursor at the end of the line
self.view.run_command("move_to", {"to": "eol"})
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to move the cursor to the end of the line. It should be obvious how to generalize!

With reference to the [API reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MoveToEolCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        # get the current "selection"
        sel = self.view.sel()

        # get the first insertion point, i.e. the cursor
        cursor_point = sel[0].begin()

        # get the region of the line we're on
        line_region = self.view.line(cursor_point)

        # clear the current selection as we're moving the cursor
        sel.clear()

        # set the selection to an empty region at the end of the line
        # i.e. move the cursor to the end of the line
        sel.add(sublime.Region(line_region.end(), line_region.end()))
```